# Cloudera Hadoop VM no eclipse

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I just downloaded the latest Cloudera VMs for both VirtualBox and VMWarePlayer and booted them. 
https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera%27s+Hadoop+Demo+VM

However, they no longer contain ANYTHING (like eclipse etc.) except an installation of hadoop.
I distinctly remember me trying out cloudera VM sometime back came with the entire installation pre-configured examples, sample data, eclipse etc. I verified that here : http://www.philippeadjiman.com/blog/2009/12/07/hadoop-tutorial-part-1-setting-up-your-mapreduce-learning-playground/

Am i doing something wrong??

Is there a place I can find the older VMs?
SJ

Comment: Why did you tag this as [tag:data-mining]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe a change which makes sense..how do they know what you want?

I believe the image is centos 5, so just do `yum search eclipse` and find the package you want(`yum install package_name`)

Comment: The problem is it came with many pre-configured mapreduce examples and sample data as well. Is there a place I can find the older image?

Comment: ahh i understand what your asking for now.  I was playing with cloudera's image about a month ago and I think they have a few basic examples in the hadoop folder(I am pretty sure I ran into some examples while trying to figure out the structure)?  But I also found this: https://github.com/cloudera/cloudera-training  might be helpful or go through their github repo and see if you can find the examples there.

Comment: I didn't find the tutorials enough so if you get the hadoop books(hadoop in action, definitive guide, or pro-hadoop) you'll get examples/tutorials as well. The source code for their examples(if you just want to read code) is all publicly available.

Comment: No problem glad I could help.  Just another note though, do a few different hadoop searches on google blogs, I found many great tutorials that involved alot of interesting data. There was one involving analyzing a data dump from wikipedia.  May give you some ideas on cool things you can do.  Best of Luck.